# Performance issue, execution error, Apex cpu limit exceed. Need help in rewriting the controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
global with sharing class test {

    public Account AccountVar { get; set; }
    public string AccountVarID { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }


    public test (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

        AccountVar = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        AccountVarID = AccountVar.Id;
        AccountName = AccountVar.Name;



    }

    @RemoteAction  
    global static
     wrapData[] loadData (string site) {
        system.debug('Entered **** : '+site);
        List<Account> AccountLvl1 = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> AccountLvl2 = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> AccountLvl3 = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> AccountLvl4 = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> AccountLvl5 = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> AccountLvl6 = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> AccountLvl7 = new List<Account>();


        List<wrapData> Content = new List<wrapData>();

        AccountLvl1 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where name = :site order by name ];

        AccountLvl2 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl1 order by name ];
        AccountLvl3 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl2 order by name ];
        AccountLvl4 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl3 order by name ];
        AccountLvl5 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl4 order by name ];
        AccountLvl6 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl5 order by name ];
        AccountLvl7 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl6 order by name ];





        for (Account a1: AccountLvl1) {
            wrapData Content1 = new wrapData();
            Content1.AccountId = a1.Id;
            Content1.AccountName = a1.Name;        
            Content1.ParentId = a1.ParentId;
            Content1.ClosedAccount = a1.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';
            Content.add(Content1);

            for (Account a2: AccountLvl2) {
                if (a2.ParentId == a1.id ) {
                    wrapData Content2 = new wrapData();
                    Content2.AccountId = a2.Id;
                    Content2.AccountName = a2.Name;
                    Content2.ParentId = a1.Id;
                    Content2.ParentAccount = a1.Name;
                    Content2.ClosedAccount = a2.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';    
                    Content.add(Content2);
                } 
                for (Account a3: AccountLvl3) {
                    if (a3.ParentId == a2.id ) {
                        wrapData Content3 = new wrapData();
                        Content3.AccountId = a3.Id;
                        Content3.AccountName = a3.Name;
                        Content3.ParentId = a2.Id;
                        Content3.ParentAccount = a2.Name;
                        Content3.ClosedAccount = a3.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';                        
                        Content.add(Content3);  
                    }
                    for (Account a4: AccountLvl4) {
                        if (a4.ParentId == a3.id ) {
                            wrapData Content4 = new wrapData();
                            Content4.AccountId = a4.Id;
                            Content4.AccountName = a4.Name;
                            Content4.ParentId = a3.Id;
                            Content4.ParentAccount = a3.Name;
                            Content4.ClosedAccount = a4.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';
                            Content.add(Content4);  
                        }
                       for (Account a5: AccountLvl5) {
                            if (a5.ParentId == a4.id ) {
                                wrapData Content5 = new wrapData();
                                Content5.AccountId = a5.Id;
                                Content5.AccountName = a5.Name;
                                Content5.ParentId = a4.Id;
                                Content5.ParentAccount = a4.Name;
                                Content5.ClosedAccount = a5.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';
                                Content.add(Content5);  
                            }
                           for (Account a6: AccountLvl6) {
                                if (a6.ParentId == a5.id ) {
                                    wrapData Content6 = new wrapData();
                                    Content6.AccountId = a6.Id;
                                    Content6.AccountName = a6.Name;
                                    Content6.ParentId = a5.Id;
                                    Content6.ParentAccount = a5.Name;
                                    Content6.ClosedAccount = a6.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';
                                    Content.add(Content6);  
                                }
                               for (Account a7: AccountLvl7) {
                                    if (a7.ParentId == a6.id ) {
                                        wrapData Content7 = new wrapData();
                                        Content7.AccountId = a7.Id;
                                        Content7.AccountName = a7.Name;
                                        Content7.ParentId = a6.Id;
                                        Content7.ParentAccount = a6.Name;
                                        Content7.ClosedAccount = a7.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';
                                        Content.add(Content7);  
                                    }

                                } 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        //Return the dynamically filtered query to the VF Page
        return Content;
    } 

    global class wrapData{
        public string AccountId {get;set;}
        public string AccountName {get;set;}
        public string ParentId {get;set;}
        public string ParentAccount {get;set;}
        public string ClosedAccount {get;set;}
    }    
 public PageReference filter() {     
        account ActId = [select id from Account where name = :AccountName];
        loadData(ActId.id);
        return null;
    } 

    public PageReference clearf() {
        string ActId = null;
        loadData(ActId);
        //getNearby(LatVar,LonVar);

        return null; 
   } 

}
```

Comment: Wow. How many levels did you nest your `for` loops? ***Seven?!***

Comment: What's the actual business use case here? Pretty sure this needs to be tackled in a very different way...

Comment: My initial thought is "build a key and do an order by"

Comment: Is there any chance you are expecting `AccountLvl1` to be top level. That is, should their `ParentId = null`?

Comment: I'd define the SortKey as "Parent.SortKey & "_" & Id. Then I'd loop through all accounts (a two level loop) - first level would be loop all accounts. Second level would be on the split of the sort key. I'd then build a map based on this key, creating elements as needed. The good thing about this is that you know that the left most keys are parents and so on, so it helps you build the key. Simple!

Comment: @AdrianLarson do you think my approach below will do the trick?

Comment: Hi Jas, there are two substantive answers to your question - it would be appropriate to indicate if they have helped you or not.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple answer, remove the nesting from the for statements and key the content with the current account id.  You already have all the data. There is no reason to rerun the child lists for each parent, (even skipping the records takes time). The only parent logic is getting the parent account name, which can easily be done in the newly created map. (Unless I mis-read the code and there is more logic to it than I saw).

** Non-Static methods removed for brevity **

**Option 1: Removing the nested for statements**

```
@RemoteAction  
global static
 wrapData[] loadData (string site) {
    system.debug('Entered **** : '+site);
    List<Account> AccountLvl1 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl2 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl3 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl4 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl5 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl6 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl7 = new List<Account>();

    Map<Id, wrapData> Content = new Map<Id, wrapData>();

    AccountLvl1 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where name = :site order by name ];

    AccountLvl2 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl1 order by name ];
    AccountLvl3 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl2 order by name ];
    AccountLvl4 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl3 order by name ];
    AccountLvl5 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl4 order by name ];
    AccountLvl6 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl5 order by name ];
    AccountLvl7 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl6 order by name ];

    for (Account a1: AccountLvl1) {
        wrapData Content1 = new wrapData();
        Content1.AccountId = a1.Id;
        Content1.AccountName = a1.Name;        
        Content1.ParentId = a1.ParentId;
        Content1.ClosedAccount = a1.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';
        ContentMap.put(Content1.AccountId, Content1);
    }
    for (Account a2: AccountLvl2) {
        wrapData Content2 = new wrapData();
        Content2.AccountId = a2.Id;
        Content2.AccountName = a2.Name;
        Content2.ParentId = a2.ParentId;
        Content2.ParentAccount = ContentMap.get(a2.ParentId).AccountName;
        Content2.ClosedAccount = a2.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';    
        ContentMap.put(Content2.AccountId, Content2);
    } 
    for (Account a3: AccountLvl3) {
        wrapData Content3 = new wrapData();
        Content3.AccountId = a3.Id;
        Content3.AccountName = a3.Name;
        Content3.ParentId = a3.ParentId;
        Content3.ParentAccount = ContentMap.get(a3.ParentId).AccountName;
        Content3.ClosedAccount = a3.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';                        
        ContentMap.put(Content3.AccountId, Content3);  
    }
    for (Account a4: AccountLvl4) {
        wrapData Content4 = new wrapData();
        Content4.AccountId = a4.Id;
        Content4.AccountName = a4.Name;
        Content4.ParentId = a4.ParentId;
        Content4.ParentAccount = ContentMap.get(a4.ParentId).AccountName;
        Content4.ClosedAccount = a4.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';
        ContentMap.put(Content4.AccountId, Content4);  
    }
    for (Account a5: AccountLvl5) {
        wrapData Content5 = new wrapData();
        Content5.AccountId = a5.Id;
        Content5.AccountName = a5.Name;
        Content5.ParentId = a5.ParentId;
        Content5.ParentAccount = ContentMap.get(a5.ParentId).AccountName;
        Content5.ClosedAccount = a5.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';
        ContentMap.put(Content5.AccountId, Content5);  
    }
    for (Account a6: AccountLvl6) {
        wrapData Content6 = new wrapData();
        Content6.AccountId = a6.Id;
        Content6.AccountName = a6.Name;
        Content6.ParentId = a6.ParentId;
        Content6.ParentAccount = ContentMap.get(a6.ParentId).AccountName;
        Content6.ClosedAccount = a6.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';
        ContentMap.put(Content6.AccountId, Content6);  
    }
    for (Account a7: AccountLvl7) {
        wrapData Content7 = new wrapData();
        Content7.AccountId = a7.Id;
        Content7.AccountName = a7.Name;
        Content7.ParentId = a7.ParentId;
        Content7.ParentAccount = contentMap.get(a7.ParentId).AccountName;
        Content7.ClosedAccount = a7.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';
        ContentMap.put(Content7.AccountId, Content7);  
    }

    //Return the dynamically filtered query to the VF Page
    return Content.values();
} 

global class wrapData{
    public string AccountId {get;set;}
    public string AccountName {get;set;}
    public string ParentId {get;set;}
    public string ParentAccount {get;set;}
    public string ClosedAccount {get;set;}
}
```

This would gain you a great deal of your efficiency back.  However we can clean up the code further like this:

**Option 2:Option 1 + Code Cleanup**

```
@RemoteAction  
global static
 wrapData[] loadData (string site) {
    system.debug('Entered **** : '+site);
    List<Account> AccountLvl1 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl2 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl3 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl4 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl5 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl6 = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> AccountLvl7 = new List<Account>();

    Map<Id, wrapData> Content = new Map<Id, wrapData>();

    AccountLvl1 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where name = :site order by name ];
    AccountLvl2 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl1 order by name ];
    AccountLvl3 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl2 order by name ];
    AccountLvl4 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl3 order by name ];
    AccountLvl5 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl4 order by name ];
    AccountLvl6 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl5 order by name ];
    AccountLvl7 = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :AccountLvl6 order by name ];

    for (Account a1: AccountLvl1) {
        contentMap.put(a1.Id, createContent(a1, contentMap));
    }
    for (Account a2: AccountLvl2) {
        contentMap.put(a2.Id, createContent(a2, contentMap));
    } 
    for (Account a3: AccountLvl3) {
        contentMap.put(a3.Id, createContent(a3, contentMap));
    }
    for (Account a4: AccountLvl4) {
        contentMap.put(a4.Id, createContent(a4, contentMap));
    }
    for (Account a5: AccountLvl5) {
        contentMap.put(a5.Id, createContent(a5, contentMap));
    }
    for (Account a6: AccountLvl6) {
        contentMap.put(a6.Id, createContent(a6, contentMap));
    }
    for (Account a7: AccountLvl7) {
        contentMap.put(a7.Id, createContent(a7, contentMap));
    }

    //Return the dynamically filtered query to the VF Page
    return Content.values();
} 

global wrapData createContent(Account a, Map<Id, wrapData> contentMap){
    wrapData Content = new wrapData();
    Content.AccountId = a.Id;
    Content.AccountName = a.Name;
    Content.ParentId = a.ParentId;
    //Null check is required for the top level creation
    if(contentMap.containsKey(a.ParentId)){
        Content.ParentAccount = contentMap.get(a.ParentId).AccountName;
    }
    Content.ClosedAccount = a.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';

    return Content;
}

global class wrapData{
    public string AccountId {get;set;}
    public string AccountName {get;set;}
    public string ParentId {get;set;}
    public string ParentAccount {get;set;}
    public string ClosedAccount {get;set;}
}
```

But lets not leave it there, this is also a great use case for recursion and removes the limitation of seven levels only:

**Option 3:Recursion**

```
@RemoteAction
global static wrapData[] loadData(String site){
    List<Account> rootAccounts = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where name = :site order by name ];

    Map<Id, wrapData> contentMap = buildContent(rootAccounts, null);

    return contentMap.values();
}

global static Map<Id, wrapData> buildContent(List<Account> accountList, Map<Id, wrapData> contentMap){
    if(contentMap == null){
        contentMap = new Map<Id, wrapData>();
    }

    for(Account a:accountList){
        contentMap.put(a.Id, createContent(a, contentMap));
    }

    //The first query does not gracefully handle circular loops in decendents. 
    //The second query can hit a 'nonselective' query error if your data size is large enough, but handles circular logic.  
    //I'm including both so that you can effectively pick your poison.

    List<Account> childAccounts = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :accountList order by name ];
    //List<Account> childAccounts = [select Id, Name, ParentId, Account_Status__c from Account where ParentId in :accountList AND Id NOT IN :contentMap.keySet() order by name ];

    if(childAccounts.isEmpty()){
        return contentMap;
    }else{
        return buildContent(childAccounts, contentMap);
    }
}

global wrapData createContent(Account a, Map<Id, wrapData> contentMap){
    wrapData Content = new wrapData();
    Content.AccountId = a.Id;
    Content.AccountName = a.Name;
    Content.ParentId = a.ParentId;
    //Null check is required for the top level creation
    if(contentMap.containsKey(a.ParentId)){
        Content.ParentAccount = contentMap.get(a.ParentId).AccountName;
    }
    Content.ClosedAccount = a.Account_Status__c == 'Current Customer'?'no':'yes';

    return Content;
}

global class wrapData{
    public string AccountId {get;set;}
    public string AccountName {get;set;}
    public string ParentId {get;set;}
    public string ParentAccount {get;set;}
    public string ClosedAccount {get;set;}
}
```

This last option is also easy to extend to provide, for example, a list of child records for each account so that you can format the data as a tree.

This was written freehand, and not compiled, so there may be minor errors but the logic should be sound. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll take a crack at an answer based on my comment.

Create a sort key on each account. eg:

```
SortKey__c = Parent.SortKey__c & "_" & Id
```

This will build you a list of keys like:

```
Account 1 00160000000KXla
Account 2 00160000000KXlx
Account 3 00160000000KXla_00D60000000KXlb
Account 4 00160000000KXlb_00D60000000KXlc
Account 5 00160000000KXlb_00D60000000KXlc_00D60000000KXld
Account 6 00160000000KXla_00D60000000KXlb_00D60000000KXle
Account 7 00160000000KXlx_00D60000000KXly
Account 7 00160000000KXlx_00D60000000KXly_00D60000000KXlz
```

Now, in your wrapdata class, make it take an account (wrapdata) map.

```
public class WrapData {
    Map<String,WrapData> accountMap {get;set;}
    ....

    public WrapData(){
        accountMap = new Map<String,WrapData>();
    }
}
```

Then, iterate.

```
Map<String,WrapData> accountMap = new Map<String,WrapData>();

for (Account a : accounts){
   String[] keys = a.SortKey__c.split('_');

   Map<String,WrapData> currentMap = accountMap;
   for (String key : keys){
       if (!accountMap.containsKey(key)){
            currentMap.put(key,new WrapData())
            //add all your account details here
       }
       else {
           currentMap = currentMap.get(key).accountMap;
       }
   }
}
return accountMap;
```

Note, this is untested (I don't have a huge structure to build this on)
However, I'm pretty confident something like this will work.

Comment: I'm a bit bleary eyed to follow it at the moment. I'll take a look in the morning. I usually try to take advantage of strict types, but your solution might work. I started typing up something mixing the idea of an `Ultimate_Parent__c` formula and hierarchy grouping. But...that's a lot to piece together. It'd be a pain for a *paid* project with clearly articulated requirements.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that too - this is something that people pay for... but sometimes the challenge gets the better of me :)